# How can I get translateX to not throw my elements, off the screen on mobile screen?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, transform

How can I get translateX to not throw my elements (materiel cards), off the screen on mobile screens after I click - to - scroll down to a scroll position? Is this a common problem with translate property on smaller screens? My problem is on www.keithcarrillo.com . Once you change screen to mobile under developer tools you can see it completely throws the cards off of screen after playing with the Prjoects button and scrolling up and down..

```
 <div id="slideMenu" className="slideMenu">
    <ul>
//=== Click Menu to scroll down, Projects Section, Blogs, & References===
      <li> <a href="#projectsClickPoint"> Projects </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#blogsClickPoint"> Blogs </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#referencesClickPoint"> References </a> </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

//=== Afeter Component Mounts =====

componentDidMount() {

    let h1Slider = document.querySelectorAll('.h1Slider');//header tags that 
                                                          //slides

      h1Slider[1].style.transform = 'translateX(900px)';
      h1Slider[0].style.transform = 'translateX(900px)';


    let updateScrollPosition = () => {
// === Compare to get the scroll position ==
      var scrollPosition = window.pageYOffset | document.body.scrollTop;
      var cardSlidePanel = document.querySelector('.slideCards');

//== if scrollPosition is greater than a number based off of length of, 
       screen 
// == then translateX back to center of screen if not throw it back off 
      screen. 
      scrollPosition > 470 ? h1Slider[0].style.transform = 'translateX(0px)' : h1Slider[0].style.transform = 'translateX(900px)';

      scrollPosition > 1600 ? h1Slider[1].style.transform = 'translateX(0px)' : h1Slider[1].style.transform = 'translateX(900px)';

      scrollPosition > 700 ? cardSlidePanel.style.transform = 'translateX(0px)' : cardSlidePanel.style.transform = 'translateX(1300px)';

      console.log(scrollPosition);
    }
 window.onscroll = () => updateScrollPosition();// Call updateScrollPosition on 
                                                //scroll event of the window
}
```